# X-editable checklist input with other option

Tags: javascript, jquery, x-editable

I use x-editable with checklist type.
It's working, but i want to add an "other" option  to my checklist, (a text input with custom value)

There is nothing about that in documentation : https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html#checklist

I hope anybody can help me.

Regards